# $stateChangeStart not being fired when state Changes in UI-Router ES6?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ecmascript-6, webpack

I am using Bable for ES6 and webpack. I am on angular 1.x.x and building an application. Till now I did not hit any problem. I want to have a functionality where I can track all the Route Changes. I am using UI-Router. The problem is that `$stateChangeStart` is not getting triggered anyways. The code is mentioned below.

```
/*All includes are taken care of. Please look at the run method*/

angular.module('chpApp', [
        uirouter,
        angular_animate,
        uibootstrap,
        formly,
        formlyBootstrap,
        ngMessages,
        angularLoadingBar,
        'ngNotificationsBar',
        'jkuri.datepicker',
        'LocalStorageModule',
        'ncy-angular-breadcrumb',
        'mgo-angular-wizard',
        'luegg.directives',
        'ngToast',
        'ui.mask',
        /*Application Modules*/
        angularnvd3,
        chpConstants,
        menu,
        header,
        breadcrumb,
        auth,
        dashboard,
        programs,
        device
    ])
    .run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', () => {
            console.log('lol')
        })
    }])
    .config(routing);
```

Please let me know what I ma  doing wrong because the state is getting changed but the `$stateChangeStart` event never gets triggered. The `run` method is the place where I am hooking up with the `$stateChangeStart` listener.

I guess its something to do with ES6 and I am not able to find any reference.
Thanks.

Comment: try $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', ...)

Comment: Why don't you strip all of that down into a [mcve] and share it with us?

Comment: @FranePoljak Dude I am using UI-Router so please read through before marking it negative!

Comment: @iH8 You can have a look the run method in the code. Sorry for so many includes. I will edit it.

Comment: It wasn't me who down voted :)

Comment: It's really best if you start with a very minimal basic usecase and then see if it still won't work. Having so many includes only makes things hell to debug. This makes it rather impossible for others to help you.

Comment: @FranePoljak Apologies if it was rude. :) Anyways why is it not at all working. During the program load the run method is triggered but after that it never does it.

Comment: @iH8 things are working flawlessly but then it comes to `$stateChangeStart` this event is not being triggered.

Comment: @iH8 there are no errors as such. Its just the $stateChangeStart does not fire. I am already on a verge of production and not able to fix this. :(

Comment: That's why i say: start with a minimal verifiable example, check the link i shared in my previous comment. It's called debugging and it's rather simple. Rip out everything until it works and then you'll know what actually caused your problem. The case you're presenting now is impossible to setup for other users so they can reproduce your problem. This is actually something which should be done by you, the asker. Please take some minutes and read this [ask] and [mcve] because in it's current form this question is really below par.

Comment: @iH8 Great I would do the same. Hope I hit a solution! :)

Comment: One thing i'm spotting though: the module for the router should be `ui.router`, not `uirouter`: `angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);` same goes for `uibootstrap` but that could be a webpack thing? i'm not sure

Comment: @iH8 its a webpack thing. But better I would look into in a proper way.

Answer (score 13):

I had a similar problem and eventually realised that the `stateChange*` events have been deprecated and disabled by default in `ui-router` 1.0. I'm using `1.0.0-alpha0`.
The functionality provided by these events can now be achieved using *transition hooks*. This is covered in the release notes for the 1.0 alpha and can be read here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/releases/tag/1.0.0alpha0

Comment: Were you able to work with it? As in Did it work with you and can you point me to some code. I am using "^1.0.0-alpha0"

Comment: I still don't see why you can't use $location service's $locationChangeStart event?

Comment: @Eoin Thank you, had the same problem and the [documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events) didn't mention anything. I now added a line mentioning this to the documentation to save people some time

Comment: broken link in answer

Answer (score 9):

Expanding on Eoins answer, you can use the hooks on $transitions in a component controller as below

```
        $transitions.onStart({}, ()=>{
            $log.log('In start')
        });
        $transitions.onFinish({}, ()=>{
            $log.log('In finish')
        });
```

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/releases/tag/1.0.0alpha0

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the other answers, you can manually activate the legacy 0.2.* stateChange-events. Save the following module as `ui-router-polyfill-wrapper.js`:

```
'use strict';

import uiRouter from 'angular-ui-router';
import 'angular-ui-router/release/stateEvents';

let module = angular
    .module('ui-router-polyfill-wrapper', [
        uiRouter,
        'ui.router.state.events',
    ]);

export default module;
```

Then put `require('./ui-router-polyfill-wrapper').default.name` instead of `require('angular-ui-router').name` in your angular app module dependency array.